# How to use env, while writing native code?

Tags: android-ndk, java-native-interface

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_marakana_NativeLib_hello (JNIEnv * env, jobject obj) 
{                                         
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Hello World!");
}
```

What is `env`? Please don't say a pointer. But What what is it pointing to? We are using `(*env)->NewStringUTF` even without initializing. How is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JNIEnv` is being passed in to your function by the VM.  It is essentially a pointer to an array of function pointers.  (There's a little more to it than that, but the function pointers are the interesting bit.)

If you have [CheckJNI](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html#extended_checking) enabled, the VM passes in a pointer to a different array of functions, which perform extended checks before calling the base function.

Every thread associated with the VM has its own `JNIEnv`.  Always use the one passed into your method, never store it in a global or static local.